# vb.net woocommerce api authentication

Tags: wordpress, vb.net, rest, oauth

I'm trying to connect to wordpress' woocommerce.com rest api.
I managed to get everything to work with postman but can't seem to get it to work with visual basic this is the code I have so far:

```
Public Class OAuth1

 Shared oauth_consumer_key As String = "blah"
 Shared oauth_consumer_Secret As String = "Blah"
 Shared Sub wooproductcreate(ByVal json)

    Dim token = Form1.TextBox1.Text

    Dim resource_url As String = "http://store.example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products"


    Dim oauth_version As String = "1.0"
    Dim oauth_signature_method As String = "HMAC-SHA256"
    Dim oauth_nonce As String = Convert.ToBase64String(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()))

    Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    Dim oauth_timestamp As String = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString()

    Dim oauth_signature As String = GeneraOAuthSignature(resource_url, _
                                                            oauth_nonce, _
                                                            oauth_signature_method, _
                                                            oauth_timestamp, _
                                                            oauth_version)
    Dim headerFormat As String = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=""{0}"",oauth_signature_method=""{1}"",oauth_timestamp=""{2}"",oauth_nonce=""{3}"",oauth_version=""{4}"",oauth_signature=""{5}"""

    Dim authHeader As String = String.Format(headerFormat, Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature))

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

    Dim req As WebRequest
    Dim res As HttpWebResponse
    Dim streamReader As StreamReader
    Dim contenidoRespuesta As String = ""
    Dim encode As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    Dim bytee = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)
    req = WebRequest.Create(resource_url)
    req.Timeout = -1
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader)
    req.ContentType = "application/json"
    req.Method = "POST"

    req.ContentLength = bytee.Length
    Dim stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(bytee, 0, bytee.Length)
    stream.Close()

    res = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    streamReader = New StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), encode)
    While True
        contenidoRespuesta = streamReader.ReadLine()

    End While

    '==========================
    'CIERRE DE STREAMS Y COMUNICACIONES
    'Abort is needed or streamReader.Close() will hang
    req.Abort()
    streamReader.Close()
    streamReader = Nothing
    res.Close()
    res = Nothing

End Sub


Shared Function GeneraOAuthSignature(ByVal stream_url As String, _
                           ByVal oauth_nonce As String, _
                           ByVal oauth_signature_method As String, _
                           ByVal oauth_timestamp As String, _
                           ByVal oauth_version As String) As String
    Dim baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_signature_method={1}&oauth_timestamp={2}" & _
                     "&oauth_nonce={3}&oauth_version={4}"

    Dim baseString As String = String.Format(baseFormat, _
                    oauth_consumer_key, _
                    oauth_signature_method, _
                    oauth_timestamp, _
                    oauth_nonce, _
                    oauth_version)

    baseString = String.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(stream_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString))

    'Using this base string, we then encrypt the data using a composite of the secret keys and the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm.
    Dim compositeKey As String = String.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_Secret))
    Dim oauth_signature As String

    Dim hasher As HMACSHA256 = New HMACSHA256(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey))
    Using hasher
        oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)))
    End Using

    Return oauth_signature
End Function

 End Class
```

The problem is that I get the response "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I'm not sure what I need to do to over come this problem.
I'm thinking it has to be how the signature is generated maybe it spitting out a invalid signature...

Wireshark outputs this from the code:

```
POST /wp-json/wc/v2/products HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="key",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1506468745",oauth_nonce="NjM2NDIwNTExNDUxOTkyMjEy",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="sig"
Content-Type: application/json
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 890
Connection: Keep-Alive

{
  "name": "Premium Quality",
  "type": "simple",
  "regular_price": "21.99",
  "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
  "short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 9
    },
    {
      "id": 14
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 26 Sep 2017 23:32:24 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Link: <http://example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

89
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_authentication_error","message":"Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.","data":{"status":401}}
0
```

When I use the postman I get a response that works and creates the product with no problem

```
POST /wp-json/wc/v2/products HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 890
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="key",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1506468730",oauth_nonce="HJVzFL",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="sig"
Postman-Token: 95240347-868c-03d0-55a9-d2fb7c51b8e2
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; woocommerce_cart_hash=some hash; wp_woocommerce_session_d0d4322f0d3b54c7984c1c37276328=somenumbers

{
  "name": "Premium Quality",
  "type": "simple",
  "regular_price": "21.99",
  "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
  "short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 9
    },
    {
      "id": 14
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Tue, 26 Sep 2017 23:32:09 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Link: <http://example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Allow: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Set-Cookie: woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; path=/
Set-Cookie: woocommerce_cart_hash=some hash; path=/
Set-Cookie: wp_woocommerce_session_d0d4322f0d3b545798c1cb7276328=some hash; expires=Thu, 28-Sep-2017 16:25:49 GMT; Max-Age=147217; path=/
Location: http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/1066
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1041
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

...........V.n#7...a
........
P...Rt..u1.5.X.....#...hn..i.....X").:.!...u.^.WW..pM.....e.......bR...(\...u..%T.....B....7..<D.i.....IG!/)... .7s.m.D..g.7s..y.Jx..r+....i....>.V...z.|fT5:>5\^<5...;.....U...2JAj.(..yL!...J.=D;d.|...*...<re.. .....u.nZ.5.......?...R.L.p....VFn"..o%.^.(.".!..."3./.....9..9...!.'.l.......r.........z.v...#; .MXR.%$.'..E...AF... '...,.`...[.v..N...U.Tf.W....o-.x.v3.;O..s...H......)...(.......w...v..6!^.~.!..r1[....$.}.\..|...fM..w..bm.R/(.J|A.....O.!.}.*..........8Z.*j...7.l..M&?]....o...=.q....V....]\..........W.......{.x&.:..Q. Ik.6....G...Hm.FY<.... ..O...VJj  ...3..;.O...#y.x...Q.)Fd......W#....Y..E......`h...U..@..[.w.!.`.]x....5.....\Rq.......3Y......A.@J.F..d...QKM&.$..P. M.w.....~<...%....<.%.F.2......g.<.Uy...".I...u...t...<..A9+...v_.\..y.v|9.xr......".S....8....U.......X/.?.y...FZy.0...^.P...(.;..7....V...^|.0>...h. .<..K.y.......c.........g...w.V\.5.,.~........;.Z............=T...Dj...... .g...v...z.?p....8..o....O.^
.....m.c
.
h.N[....    .......v_...`
.b3?,.O9...!.|%a1.Ew.o.........[..
..
```

I've tried a few different things and have improved the code. However I still can't seem to get the signature to generate correctly it's always saying it doesn't match.

```
Imports RestSharp Imports System.Text 
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class Form1

    Shared oauth_consumer_key As String = "ck_xxx"
    Shared oauth_consumer_Secret As String = "cs_XXX"


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim resource_url As String = "http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products"

        Dim oauth_signature_method As String = "HMAC-SHA256"
        Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
        Dim oauth_timestamp As String = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString()
        Dim oauth_nonce As String = Convert.ToBase64String(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()))
        Dim oauth_version As String = "1.0"

        Dim oauth_signature As String = GeneraOAuthSignature(resource_url, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_version)

        Dim auth As String = "oauth_consumer_key=""" & oauth_consumer_key & """,oauth_signature_method=""" & oauth_signature_method & """,oauth_timestamp=""" & oauth_timestamp & """,oauth_nonce=""" & oauth_nonce & """,oauth_version=""" & oauth_version & """,oauth_signature=""" & oauth_signature & """"
        MsgBox(auth)
        Dim client = New RestClient(resource_url)
        Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json")
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "OAuth " & auth)
        request.AddParameter("application/json", TextBox1.Text, ParameterType.RequestBody)
        Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
        MsgBox(response.Content)
    End Sub

    Shared Function GeneraOAuthSignature(ByVal stream_url As String, ByVal oauth_nonce As String, ByVal oauth_signature_method As String, ByVal oauth_timestamp As String, ByVal oauth_version As String) As String
        'The next step is to generate an encrypted oAuth signature which will be use to validate the request.
        'To do this, all of the request data is concatenated into a particular format as follows
        Dim baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_version={4}"

        Dim baseString As String = String.Format(baseFormat, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_version)

        baseString = String.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(stream_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString))
        MsgBox(baseString)
        Dim compositeKey As String = Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_Secret)

        'Using this base string, we then encrypt the data using a composite of the secret keys and the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm.
        Dim oauth_signature As String

        Dim hasher As HMACSHA256 = New HMACSHA256(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey))
        Using hasher
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)))
        End Using

        Return oauth_signature
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that code that you wrote, it's easier than you think.
Read the [Usage](https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET#usage) section at the XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET github repo.

Also, you can install the **WooCommerceNet** from the NuGets:
`VS > Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet`